# Ways to add to $N$ using positive integers $\le N$

Tags: combinatorics

Given a number $N$ I want to find the number of ways to add up to it using integers in the range [1, N].

I do not want to count the same thing more than once, but I do want different orders.

For example, for $N=4$:

$1+1+2$ is a solution. So it $1+2+1$. But $1+1+2$ should not be counted twice, that is swapping the 2 1's is not a unique solution.

The full solution set for $N=4$ should be:

$1+1+1+1$
$2+1+1$
$1+2+1$
$1+1+2$
$2+2$
$3+1$
$1+3$
$4$

so I want $8$ for $N=4$

Comment: What you are asking for are called compositions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Comment: @Patrick this wasn't part of the question, but what would be a good way to enumerate through the possibilities?

Comment: We know the first number has to be somewhere between 1 and N. Pick one, call it x, and then recursively enumerate all sequences summing to N-x.

Comment: @gregkow picking one doesn't work right? I need to iterate through 1 to N and append all the recursive call results to a solution set

Comment: You would, yeah. You repeat the "pick one" step until all have been chosen.

Comment: A similar question was asked recently, but it was not nearly as well phrased as this was. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827536/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $$2^{N-1}$$ ways to form a composition of the number $N$.  In your example, $N=4$ and the total number of compositions is $2^{4-1} = 8$ as you observed.

To see why this is the right answer, imagine you have $N$ coins lined up on the table.  You are going to insert dividers between some of the coins to separate the coins into groups.    So for example with $N=7$ we might have

$$\bullet \mid \bullet \bullet \bullet \mid \bullet \mid\bullet \bullet $$

Here we've composed $7 = 1+3+1+2$.  The compositions of $7$ as a sum of positive integers are in one-to-one correspondence with the possible positions of the dividers: for each sum, there is exactly one corresponding set of dividers.  There are $N-1$ positions for the dividers, and each position might have a divider or lack a divider, so there are $2^{N-1}$ possible ways to insert the dividers, and so $2^{N-1}$ compositions.

(Had you simply tabulated the number of compositions of $N$ for $N=1, 2, 3, 4$ you might have noticed  this yourself.)

To enumerate the possibilities, enumerate the possible sets of positions for the dividers, which are simply the base-2 numerals from $0$ through $2^{N-1}-1$, and for each one calculate the corresponding  composition. [Here is example code](https://github.com/mjdominus/perl-misc/blob/master/compositions).

Comment: This is a very good answer. I'm curious why you made it community wiki? As an aside: you couldn't have picked a worse language than perl for me to understand :). It's okay, I wrote a solution in java before I saw that post anyway. But thanks for the effort!

Comment: I make all my answers community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a recursive solution. Let $A(n)$ represent the number of ways to represent $n$ in the form you suggest and now consider $A(n+1)$. Let the first contribution in our sum be $i$ where $1 \leq i \leq n+1$, then the sum of the remaining terms is $n+1-i$ and so there are precisely $A(n+1-i)$ ways to represent the remaining terms.